# Controller help and functions 

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I have a general `create` function that submits a new user to the database - this works fine.  Where I am is stuck is the following.

- I know that I need the user that is signing up to have clicked the link in the email before the account can login.  **How do I implement that into my** `if statement` **when I run the create function?**
- I am a bit confused as to how to set my errors if any thing is correct or wrong to do with the activation process I have currently set the messages using `$this->form_validation->set_message();`. **Do I need to use set_flashdata();? and how will echo these into the view?**

When I `create` a new user I have the `userActive` field set at `0` by default and also the default group is set to `users`

**Controller:**

```
   <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $data['companyName'] = $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName;
        $data['pageTitle'] = "Create User";
        $this->load->view('frontend/assets/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('frontend/users', $data);
        $this->load->view('frontend/assets/footer');
    }

    public function create(){   

        //If form validation fails load previous page with errors else do the job and insert data into db

        if($this->form_validation->run('createUser') == FALSE)
        {
            $data['success'] = "";
        }else{
            $username = $this->input->post('userName');
            $password = $this->input->post('userPassword');
            $firstname = $this->input->post('userFirstName');
            $lastname = $this->input->post('userLastName');
            $email = $this->input->post('userEmail');

            $passwordHash = $this->encrypt->sha1($password); // Lets encrypt the password why sha1?  MD5 is for tossers

            $activateCode = $this->_activateCode(10);

            // If the data is correct follow through with db insert

            if($this->users_model->createUser($username,$passwordHash,$firstname,$lastname,$email,$activateCode))
            {
                $data['success'] = TRUE;

                redirect('frontend/users/create','refresh');

            }

        }
        $data['companyName'] = $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName;
        $data['pageTitle'] = "Create User";
        $this->load->view('frontend/assets/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('frontend/user_create', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/assets/footer');

        echo get_class($this);
        var_dump(method_exists($this, '_activateCode'));
    }

    function _userRegEmail($activateCode,$email,$firstname,$lastname){
        $data['companyName'] = $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName;
        $data['companyEmail'] = $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyEmail;
        $data['companyContact'] = $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreContactName;
        $data['firstName'] = $firstName;
        $data['lastName'] = $lastname;
        $data['email'] = $email;
        $data['activateCode'] = $activateCode;

        $this->email->from($this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyEmail, $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName);
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject($this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName, 'User Registration Confirmation');

        $messageContent= $this->load->view('email_templates/userReg','', TRUE);

        $this->email->message($messageContent);

        //$this->email->send();
    }

    function usersconfirm(){

        $activateCode = $this->uri->segment(3);

        if($activateCode == '')
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('userConfirmError', 'Sorry you did not have a correct Activation Code.');
        }
            $userConfirmed = $this->users_model->confirm_user($activateCode);

            if($userConfirmed){
                $this->form_validation->set_message('userConfirmed', 'Thanks your account is now active you may login!');
            }else{
                $this->form_validation->set_message('userRecord', 'I am sorry we do not have any details with that Activation Code');
            }
    }

     function _username_check($username)
    {
        if($this->users_model->username_taken($username))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'Sorry the username %s is taken!');
            return FALSE;
        }else{
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    function _email_check($email)
    {
        if($this->users_model->email_check($email))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('email_check','Sorry there is already a user with this %s');
            return FALSE;
        }else{
            return TRUE;
        }

    }

   function _activateCode($length)
    {
        return random_string('alnum', $length);
    }

}

/* End of file users.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/users.php */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine if the user has clicked the activation link by checking the database for `userActive` in your if statement.

You can use flash data, sure. You can retrieve flash data with: 
`$this->session->flashdata('item');` to echo out to the view.

See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html > flash data

Comment: Thanks,  I seem to be having an issue that I am still being added to the database without any sign of an email.  Even through I have the callback function set to check for the user it is also still adding

Comment: That's to be expected: the user is added to the db when they register! The email is to set their account to ACTIVE when they click the link. You don't let the user into the site unless their account is ACTIVE. So, register -> user in db with account_active = 0; email sent; click link -> account_active = 1

Comment: I know but its still adding even though the username admin exists and I am getting no call back but I am getting validation when the form is "required" but nothing past that.

Comment: OK, someone edited out the validation rules, but in the username check your callback is missing an underscore. In your username validation rule change `callback_username_check` to `callback__username_check`; you need the extra underscore because the method is private. Oh, and same will go for the email callback.